# Bash: get TAB completions as a list

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I would like to know a way to get a list of possible completions of a command but without executing it. For example, to get a list of linux modules which can be load, you could do:

```
$ sudo modprobe [TAB][TAB]
... list of completions
```

But, what if a want to "save" that list in a file? I think there should be any option of `complete` command for that purpose:

```
$ complete <whanever option> modprobe > modprobe-completion-list.txt
```

or, for partial completions:

```
$ complete <whanever options> "modprobe i2" > modules-prefix-i2-list.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to do this in general would be `compgen`.  But if you're using the standard bash-completions, the `modprobe` case won't work, since it goes through a shell function call.  While those are supported by `compgen`, the documentation and inline help kindly inform it probably won't do what you want.

```
$ complete -p modprobe
complete -F _modprobe modprobe
$ compgen -F _modprobe
bash: compgen: warning: -F option may not work as you expect
```

It's documented, so it's probably for a good reason; that reason just happens to be beyond me.

A very hacky kludge to get your results anyway is to script readline. I wouldn't put something like that in a production process, but it works fine in the terminal, and though I haven't tested it in more isolated contexts (cron, daemons), it might actually work there too.

```
$ echo -en "bind 'set page-completions Off'
            bind 'set completion-query-items 0'
            sudo modprobe \t\t\x15" | bash -i
$ sudo modprobe 
3c574_cs                       msi-laptop
3c589_cs                       msi-wmi
3c59x                          msp3400
3w-9xxx                        mspro_block
  (...)
ms_block                       zr36067
msdos                          zr364xx
msi001                         zram
msi2500                        
$ exit
```

Decomposed:

- `bind 'set page-completions Off'` avoids any “--More--” prompting that would be uneasy to script through without knowing the number of pages we're getting.
- `set completion-query-items 0` avoids the “Display all 3598 possibilities? (y or n)” prompting.
- `sudo modprobe \t\t` is pretty self-explanatory. Don't forget the space before the tabs.
- `\x15` is hex for <kbd>C-u</kbd>, bound by default to `unix-line-discard`, to clear the line so the `sudo modprobe` isn't actually run.

Keep in mind just about all the output in this example goes to stderr. So if you want to extract it for filtering, you'll need some combination of `2> file`, `2>&1` and `|&`.

Alternative best of both worlds, automating [@betterworld's <kbd>M-*</kbd> trick:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32523372/12274)

```
$ echo -en 'sudo modprobe \e*\x01\ed\edecho' | bash -i 2>/dev/null
```

This strongly assumes emacs editing mode (the default). Prepend a `set -o emacs\n` if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

Type `sudo modprobe <Esc>*`, this should insert all completions into your command line.  Then edit the line so that it becomes `echo [list of modules] > file`